# Round current time up and down

Tags: bash, date

I'm trying to figure out how to get the current hour rounded down to start of the hour and the next hour in bash?

For example, if I run my script:

> ./printHour.sh

and let's say the current time at execution is **13:04:12** - it would print

```
current hour is: 13:00:00 
next hour is: 14:00:00
```

Progress so far: (but this gives 1hour ago so it **does not** work) - any ideas?

```
lastHour=$(date -d '1 hour ago' "+%H:%M:%S")
echo "current hour is: "$lastHour
```

Comment: Your `lastHour` method doesn't work for me, it says `current hour is: 13:12:09`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - yes it doesn't work... :( I need some help to make it work. I'm new to bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested as per shown samples, my `date` is GNU date version.

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash   
currentHour=$(date "+%H:00:00")
nextHour=$(date -d '+1 hour' "+%H:00:00")

echo "current hour is: $currentHour"
echo "next hour is: $nextHour"
```

When I run above script I get as follows:

```
current hour is: 06:00:00
next hour is: 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this utility function:

```sh
hrdt() { date -d "${1?} hour ago" '+%H:00:00'; }
```

**Testing:**

```sh
> hrdt
bash: 1: parameter not set

> hrdt 0
08:00:00

> hrdt 1
07:00:00

> hrdt 2
06:00:00

> hrdt 3
05:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't need anything special so this should do it:

```
date -d '1 hour ago' "+%H:00:00"
```

Why bother when you want exactly *the hour* where both `%M` and `%S` are expected to be zero?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `date` in this case; as seen below, built-in `printf` can generate formatted date-time strings too. Here `-1` represents current time, and `EPOCHSECONDS` is a dynamic variable that expands to the number of seconds since epoch.

```
$ printf 'current hour is: %(%H)T:00:00\n' -1
current hour is: 17:00:00
$
$ printf 'next hour is: %(%H)T:00:00\n' $((EPOCHSECONDS + 3600))
next hour is: 18:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk,

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { st=systime(); 
         print "current hour=" strftime("%F %H:00:00",st); 
         print "next hour=" strftime("%F %H:00:00",st+(60*60)) } '
current hour=2020-12-26 23:00:00
next hour=2020-12-27 00:00:00
$
```